# Axis2 and Web-Service

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have a web-service, I used `Axis2-1.5.0` to access it, but I have two questions:

1. It had generated most of classes as static, why it did so?

   `[ServiceName]ServiceStub` has all source, which ended up with > 9 Mb, is there any parameter I can pass so these classes got separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the options at

http://ws.apache.org/axis2/tools/1_0/CodegenToolReference.html

Of interest to you may be

```
-u
--unpack-classes    
Unpack classes. This option specifies whether to unpack the classes and generate separate classes for the databinders.
```

However, last time I used it (on a salesforce.com wsdl), I still got a giant 10 MB stub, because the WSDL was monolithic. So yes, this will try to unpack classes, but if it is written as a single class with 10000 methods on the server side, it will still be big.

As to static, I think it depends on the type of generator you use. It doesn't have to be.

```
-d  
--databinding-method    
Specifies the Databinding framework. valid values are xmlbeans, adb, jibx, and none. Default is adb.
```